# Заполнение стека на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, стек

Нужно реализовать заполнение стека числами с консоли. Количество стеков и уровень заполнения вводятся пользователем. Стек делаем через список.

Вот что я сделал:

```
a2=[]
a = []
n=int(input("Введите количество стеков: "))
level=int(input("Введите уровень заполнения: "))
i=0
for n in range(n):
    for i in range(level):
        a.append(input("Введите элементы " + str(n) + " стека через пробел:").split())
        i+=1
    i=0
a2 = [x for x in a if x] 
print(a2)
print("Количество стеков: "+str(len(a2)))
print("Количество элементов в 1 стеке = "+str(len(a2[0])))
n2=len(a2)
for i in range(n2-1):
i +=1
print("Количество элементов в "+str(i+1)+" стеке = "+str(len(a2[i])))
```

Строка  a2 = [x for x in a if x] заполняет список a2 списком a. А нужно чтобы каждый элемент a2 был длиною согласно уровню заполнения. Подскажите как это сделать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

вы можете не создавать промежуточный список

```
a2=[]
n=int(input("Введите количество стеков: "))
for n in range(n):
        a2.append(input("Введите элементы " + str(n) + " стека через пробел:").split())
print(a2)
```

Comment: А как же уровень заполнения ? Мне нужно чтобы в каждой ячейке было только указанное к-во level элементов.

Comment: сколько введут чисед в строку, столько в этом стеке и будет